# How to fix a Sitecom WL-330 wireless range extender 300N that stops repeating, even after a device reset?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-bridge

After having setup a [Sitecom 300N wireless range extender](http://www.sitecom.com/en/wireless-range-extender-n300/wl-330/p/217) ([WL-330](http://www.sitecom.com/en/wireless-range-extender-n300/wl-330/p/217) v1 002) it suddenly stopped working after months of usage.

Even after powering the device off and back on again, and after re-applying its settings, the wireless repeater doesn't want to repeat the wireless signal again.

How to fix this?

Comment: Depending how many months: repair/replace under warranty or trash/recycle and buy [another|something different this time.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. Factory reset

First factory reset the WL-330 device.

Go to the WL-330 web admin interface, tab "Toolbox" -> tab "Back-up" -> label "Restore to Factory default" choose the `[ Reset ]` button.

In case you can't access the web admin interface, you can also press the "Reset" button (on the rear panel of the device) and hold for 10 seconds to restore all settings to factory defaults.

#### 2. Site Survey

Secondly re-issue a site survey. Go to tab "Basic Settings" -> label "Site Survey:" -> button `[ Site Survey ]` and select your Wi-Fi SSID, finally choose button `[ Done ]`.

#### 3. Channel number

At the "Basic Settings" screen, verify that the Wi-Fi channel number is identical to the one, chosen in the Site Survey.

#### 4. Apply basic settings

Now apply the basic settings, and at the "Save settings successfully!"  screen choose button `[ Continue ]` to set the password before restarting the device.

#### 5. Set Wi-Fi security

Next go to "Advanced Settings" -> "Security". In most cases the "Encryption" drop down menu can be changed to "WPA Pre-Shared Key".

When you are not sure which value to choose and your are working on a Mac, connect to the wireless network you wish to repeat, then press the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-key while clicking on the Wi-Fi icon ([image: Wi-Fi menu bar icon]) in the menu bar. This will show detailed settings like PHY mode, BSSID, Channel number, Security, etcetera.

#### 6. Set Wi-Fi password

Next fill out your Wi-Fi password near the "Pre-Shared Key" label and press `[ Apply ]`. In the following "Save settings successfully!" screen you now choose for `[ Apply ]` again to store all your settings and restart the Wi-Fi repeater configured with your new settings.

#### 7. Disable DHCP server (optional)

In case you also want to **bridge on the wired ethernet interface**, in other words when connecting your computer via a cable to the WL-330 and wish to have an IP address from the same IP range as when connecting directly to the wireless network, then you need to disable the DHCP server that is built in to the WL-330. Go to tab "Toolbox" -> label "DHCP Server :" -> drop down menu "Enabled" and change that to "Disabled", `[ Apply ]` and `[ Apply ]`.